# Get HTTP request info with Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to know how can I get a HTTP request information from Java, I am using Restlet framework but I don't want to limit it with that. As I have been struggling to figure it out with restlet and yet I can't. I am attaching a screenshot of my GAE console log,

[image]

I need to get that locahost (domain), it could be abc.com or xyz.com in actual production environment.

Here is the restlet code I have for this app:

```
    Redirector proxy = new Redirector(getContext(), target,
            Redirector.MODE_SERVER_OUTBOUND){

        String target = "https://dl.x.com/u/123/";

        @Override
        public void handle(Request request, Response response) {
            String path = request.getResourceRef().getHostIdentifier() +
                request.getResourceRef().getPath();
            try {
                URL url = new URL(path);
                String host = url.getHost();
                String pathParts = url.getPath();
                if(pathParts.isEmpty() || pathParts.equals(ROOT_URI)){
                    pathParts = "/index.html"; // Hard-wired for now
                }
                String targetPattern = target + host + pathParts;
                System.out.println("Target URL = " + targetPattern);
                this.setTargetTemplate(targetPattern);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            super.handle(request, response);
        }
    };
    getConnectorService().getClientProtocols().add(Protocol.HTTP);
    return proxy;
}
```

The problem here is the String `host` gets the value of `app-x.appspot.com`, I need to get the one shown in the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information from the request-object:

```
request.getRequestURI()
```